# When I add a column in the database, under what conditions do I need to update my EDMX?

Tags: entity-framework

When I add a column in the database, under what conditions do I need to update my EDMX?

To elaborate:

I know if I add a non-nullable field, I need to update the model if I want to write to the database.  What if just I want to read?

What if it's a nullable field?  Can I both read and write?

What if I were to change the primary key to the new column but the edmx still has the old column as primary?

Comment: Context for the curious: the existing database has a very dated schema (circa 1993) supported by a desktop application.  I'm wondering what sort of improvements I can make without having to update and redeploy the application.  The application's using EF6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you want to port an old database, you need to make sure that every table in your database must have a primary key. This is the only requirement for creating the EDMX.

2) If you've added a column in a table at database side, and have not updated edmx, then you'll simply not be  able to use that column though EntityFramework.

If you create a non nullable column with no default value, the insert operation will fail with exception "Cannot insert null into column , statement terminated". And the you'll not be able to read values of that column using entityframeowrk, unless you update the edmx.

3) If you've changed the primary key of any table at database side, and if the edmx is not aware of that, your application might create a runtime exception when performing operations with that table.

Remember, Entity Framework creates SQL queries depending upon its knowledge of database(which is defined in EDMX). So if EDMX is incorrect, the resulting SQL queries so generated might lead to problems at runtime.

Comment: I disagree with point 2 -- I know that if I add a non-nullable field without a default value, an insert or update query will fail (I forget the exact exception off-hand).  Presumably all reads should work and it shouldn't matter if I change the primary key for the reason you stated -- it just generates SQL.  But, you know... it can be weird sometimes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you create a non nullable column with no default value, the insert operation will fail with exception "Cannot insert  null into column <column-name>, statement terminated". And the you'll not be able to read values of that column either unless you update the edmx.

Comment: Updating my answer too.